# Delete posts older than 2 years in wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to delete all that posts programmatically which are older than two years on my WordPress site. there are around 37000 posts. need help to delete it in bulk. how it is possible.? what will be the easiest way to delete.?

Comment: what you have tried & what issues you faced ?

Comment: I didn't try anything yet. Currently, I am just going manually to do this. Thank you

Comment: check my answer, you can run this query into your phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code.. Please read my comments in the code for more understanding. Function will go into your functions.php

```
function get_delete_old_post() {
    // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array(
        'fields'         => 'ids', // Only get post ID's to improve performance
        'post_type'      => array( 'post' ), //post type if you are using default than it will be post
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',//fetch all posts,
        'date_query'     => array(
                                    'column'  => 'post_date',
                                    'before'   => '-2 years'
                                )//date query for before 2 years you can set date as well here 
        );

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // The Loop
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            //delete post code
            //wp_trash_post( get_the_ID() );  use this function if you have custom post type
            wp_delete_post(get_the_ID(),true); //use this function if you are working with default posts
        }    
    } else {
        // no posts found
        return false;

    }
    die();
    // Restore original Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

}

add_action('init','get_delete_old_post');
```

Comment: wp_trash_post() - Move a post or page to the Trash. Why do you recommended to use it on custom post type?

Answer (score 2):

The direct bulk method might be to speak some raw SQL (`DELETE FROM ...`), but unless you have taken the time to learn WordPress internals, I would not suggest this route.  Instead -- as with many tasks WordPress -- look for a plugin.  Consider [this search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/delete/), which presents [Bulk Delete](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bulk-delete/) as the top options.

Indeed, Bulk Delete is a plugin we have used in office for just such an occurrence.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Run this sql query

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(`post_date`) >= 2;
```

Comment: This will leave you with orphaned postmeta-entries that you'll have to take care of at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You might just like this plugin (which I wrote) Auto Prune Posts, it will delete posts after , say 2 years, based on taxonomy + age. https://wordpress.org/plugins/auto-prune-posts/

When you just "DELETE FROM .. "  you WILL end up with orphaned data in at least the postmeta table. I think you do not want that.